# Newly created react app is giving an error without me editing anything at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, progressive-web-apps

I just created a new react app with `npx create-react-app appname --template cra-template-pwa`. As soon as it's done (and I saw Happy Hacking), I ran `npm audit fix` to fix tewo issues which didn't work and then I entered `npm run build` and I got an error. I didn't even open a text editor. This is the error:

```
\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js:664
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        ^

TypeError: MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor
    at module.exports (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\production\mgclient\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js:664:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\productionmgclient\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\build.js:58:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mgclient@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mgclient@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-14T21_45_45_683Z-debug.log
```

and when I run `npm start`, it runs with the following warnings:

```
 [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4220) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
Starting the development server...
Compiled successfully!

You can now view mgclient in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://172.17.62.49:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

assets by path static/ 1.49 MiB
  asset static/js/bundle.js 1.48 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_es5_min_js.chunk.js 5.35 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
  asset static/media/logo.103b5fa18196d5665a7e12318285c916.svg 2.61 KiB [emitted] (auxiliary name: main)
asset index.html 1.66 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 578 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 31.3 KiB 15 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.35 MiB 90 modules
modules by path ./src/ 24.2 KiB
  modules by path ./src/*.js 11.8 KiB
    ./src/index.js 2.17 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.js 2.57 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/serviceWorkerRegistration.js 5.63 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/reportWebVitals.js 1.41 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/*.css 8.82 KiB
    ./src/index.css 2.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css 1.37 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.css 2.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/App.css 2 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./src/logo.svg 3.61 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.66.0 compiled successfully in 300030 ms
```

What does this error mean and what do I have to do.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: npx create-react-app appname --template pwa

Comment: When you ran npm audit fix, perhaps you upgraded some packages to a new version that isn't backwards-compatible. Try deleting it and re-doing the process. See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/3

Comment: @JafarJabr please what does `npx create-react-app appname --template pwa` do? how is it different from `npm create-react-app appname --template cra-template-pwa`?

Comment: @code `npm audit fix` didn't fix anything. and the initialized git repo that comes with react-app didn't register any change at all anywhere in the code's directory!

Comment: @samuei Yes Yes, I just followed the instruction for npm and it worked. No more errors when I run build. Thank you very much! I appreciate!